# Add a new type of Unordered List to RAD Editor

Tags: telerik, sitecore7, radeditor

I'm trying to add functionality to RAD Editor for an unordered list with a class (whatever):

```
<ul class="whatever">
  <li>thing</li>
</ul>
```

I have:

- The button showing up
- The command registered, and firing

I've decompiled RAD Editor assembly but am having trouble matching what I see in RadEditor.js with actual Javascript I'm seeing in the browser.

**Update:**  I decompiled Telerik.Web.UI and that has the Javascript I'm seeing in my browser, but still would take any help I can get.

**Update 2:**
Here's what I have; get ULs before and after adding the new one, then find the new one, and add a class.

```
RadEditorCommandList["InsertCheckmarkList"] = function (commandName, editor, tool) {
editor.setFocus();
var elementsBefore = editor.get_document().getElementsByTagName('ul');
elementsBefore = Array.prototype.slice.call(elementsBefore);

editor.executeCommand(new Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.InsertListCommand(editor.getLocalizedString("InsertUnorderedList"), editor.get_contentWindow(), editor.get_newLineMode() == Telerik.Web.UI.EditorNewLineModes.Br, "InsertUnorderedList", "check", editor));

var elementsAfter = editor.get_document().getElementsByTagName('ul');
elementsAfter = Array.prototype.slice.call(elementsAfter);

var newElement;
for (var i = 0; i < elementsAfter.length; i++) {
    if (elementsBefore.indexOf(elementsAfter[i]) == -1) {
        newElement = elementsAfter[i];
        break;
    }
}

if (newElement) {
    newElement.className += " whatever";
}
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to put this in Content Editor (Ribbon) or RTE?

Comment: @MSRob RTE.  I think I have a (bad?) solution currently.  I'll update with what I have